# Is the poset of all subsets of a collection of sets rank-unimodal?

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory, algebraic-combinatorics

I'm working on Richard P. Stanley's Algebraic Combinatorics and have been stuck on this problem for a while:

Let $S_1, S_2,..., S_{k}$ be finite sets with $\#S_1 = \#S_2 = ... = \#S_{k}$. Let $P$ be the poset of all sets $T$ contained in some $S_{i}$, ordered by inclusion. In symbols, \begin{equation} P = 2^{S_1} \cup 2^{S_2} \cup ... \cup 2^{S_{k}} \end{equation} where $2^{S}$ denotes the set of all subsets of $S$. Is $P$ always rank-unimodal?

I think I've made progress, but I'm not sure where to go right now. I think that $P$ is always rank unimodal and I suspect that the "middle" level is always the largest, and I'm trying to show this inductively; the condition holds for all cases of size 1, then 2, and so on, and if it works for $k$ sets of some size, it works for $k + 1$ of that size. The poset of subsets of a single set is rank-unimodal, and the poset formed by multiple singleton sets is too, so this provides base cases.

Given a collection of sets that we wish to show satisfy the property, if no set is contained within the union of the others, every set must have an element not contained in any other set. For set $S_{i}$, call one such element $a_{i}$. Ignoring each $a_{i}$, the condition must be satisfied by the sets by our inductive hypotheses. We now also have $k {\#S \choose n}$ additional sets of each size $n$, and adding these retains rank-unimodality (and possibly the middle level being the largest, but I don't know if it's necessarily true).

If some set is contained in the union of the others, WLOG let $S_{k}$ be such a set. From here, I have had trouble counting "new" sets of each size and relating the sizes of levels.

Any hints or help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried finding an order raising operator for each rank to prove that the poset is Sperner? I believe this works, but am still figuring out the details. Namely, each poset $2^{S_r}$ comes with its own order raising operators $U^r_i:\mathbb R(2^{S_r})_i\to \mathbb R(2^{S_r})_{i+1}$ for $i\in\{0,\dots,|S_r|\}$, which can be extended to be map defined on all of $\mathbb R(2^{S_1}\cup \dots 2^{S_k})$ by saying $U^r_i(T)=0$ when $T\not\subseteq S_r$. I think that you can prove $U^1_i+U^2_i+\dots+U^k_i$ is invertible, hence the poset is Sterner...

Comment: @MikeEarnest I haven't, but that seems like a great idea, thank you! The chapter that this was in focuses a good amount on the Sperner property, which makes it seem even more reasonable. I'll think about it some more!

Comment: JSYK, after some more though, I am less sure if this method is fruitful. Recall for proving $2^S$ is Sperner, they showed $U_i$ is invertible by showing $D_{i+1}U_i=U_{i-1}D_i+(n-2i)I$ (something like that), and both the $DU$ and $UD$ are positive semi-definite since the $U$'s are the transposes of the $D$'s, so positive eigenvalues so $U_i$ invertible. But, for a similar method, you would need $(D_{i+1}^1+\dots+D_{i+1}^k)(U_i^1+\dots+U_i^k)$ being psd, and the cross terms get messy, so I am unsure. I'll keep thinking, I hope you can come up with something as well.

Comment: @MikeEarnest thanks for letting me know! I think that proving it's Sperner isn't fully necessary as long as we can show that there's an order matching from $P_{i}$ to $P_{i + 1}$ for all $i$ up to some level and $P_{i + 1}$ to $P_{i}$ afterwards. Lemma 4.5 of Stanley's Algebraic Combinatorics says that if there's a one-to-one function from $\mathbb{R}P_{i}$ to $\mathbb{R}P_{i + 1}$ such that each $U(x)$ maps $x$ to a linear combination of elements covering it, then there's an order matching from $P_{i}$ to $P_{i + 1}$, so maybe this can be used without too much messy algebra.